# SQL Server 2005 - SUM'ing one field, but only for the first occurence of a second field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, conditional-statements

#### Platform: SQL Server 2005 Express

Disclaimer: I’m quite a novice to SQL and so if you are happy to help with what may be a very simple question, then I won’t be offended if you talk slowly and use small words :-)

I have a table where I want to SUM the contents of multiple rows.  However, I want to SUM one column only for the first occurrence of text in a different column.

```
Table schema for table 'tblMain'
fldOne {varchar(100)}    Example contents: “Dandelion“
fldTwo {varchar(8)}      Example contents: “01:00:00” (represents hh:mm:ss)
fldThree {numeric(10,0)} Example contents: “65”
```

Contents of table:

```
Row number      fldOne       fldTwo     fldThree
------------------------------------------------
1               Dandelion    01:00:00   99
2               Daisy        02:15:00   88
3               Dandelion    00:45:00   77
4               Dandelion    00:30:00   10
5               Dandelion    00:15:00   200
6               Rose         01:30:00   55
7               Daisy        01:00:00   22
etc. ad nausium
```

If I use:

```
Select * from tblMain where fldTwo < ’05:00:00’ order by fldOne, fldTwo desc
```

Then all rows are correctly returned, ordered by fldOne and then fldTwo in descending order (although in the example data I've shown, all the data is already in the correct order!)

What I’d like to do is get the SUM of each *fldThree*, but only from the first occurrence of each *fldOne*.

So, SUM the first Dandelion, Daisy and Rose that I come across. E.g.
99+88+55

At the moment, I’m doing this programmatically;  return a RecordSet from the Select statement above, and *MoveNext* through each returned row, only adding *fldThree* to my ‘total’ if I’ve never seen the text from *fldOne* before.  It works, but most of the Select queries return over 100k rows and so it’s quite slow (slow being a relative term – it takes about 50 seconds on my setup).

The actual select statement (selecting about 100k rows from 1.5m total rows) completes in under a second which is fine.  The current programatic loop is quite small and tight, it's just the number of loops through the RecordSet that takes time.  I'm using adOpenForwardOnly and adLockReadOnly when I open the record set.

This is a routine that basically runs continuously as more data is added,  and also the *fldTwo* 'times' vary, so I can't be more specific with the Select statement.

Everything that I’ve so far managed to do natively with SQL seems to run quickly and I’m hoping I can take the logic (and work) away from my program and get SQL to take the strain.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Kaf - yes, MS SQL 2005 Express.

Comment: People already have answered, so I don't have to. I know you are new, so please try to tag your question with required tags which would be helpful when answering. In return you would get relavent answers quickly.

Comment: Hi @Kaf.   I'm grateful for the patience that people show when someone is new to a forum and appologies if I've missed some points.  I used the tags 'SQL', 'SUM' and 'CONDITIONAL' and tried '2005' but as a new user, I couldn't create a new tag.  My mistake was missing the 'sql-server' tag (now fixed).  I did add a title at the start of the post that was meant to clarify things, but appreciate it wasn't as good as a proper tag.  All tags now sorted, which will help others who come looking for the ace answers from Hamlet and Gordon. Regards, Ian.

Comment: Hay, that is fine. It was just some useful tips. There are lots of nice people here willing to offer there knowledge and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to approach this is with window functions.  These let you enumerate the rows within a group.  However, you need some way to identify the first row.  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so you need a column to specify the ordering.  Here are some ideas.

If you have an id column, which is defined as an `identity` so it is autoincremented:

```
select sum(fldThree)
from (select m.*,
            row_number() over (partition by fldOne order by id) as seqnum
      from tblMain m
     ) m
where seqnum = 1
```

To get an arbitrary row, you could use:

```
select sum(fldThree)
from (select m.*,
            row_number() over (partition by fldOne order by (select NULL as noorder)) as seqnum
      from tblMain m
     ) m
where seqnum = 1
```

Or, if FldTwo has the values in reverse order:

```
select sum(fldThree)
from (select m.*,
            row_number() over (partition by fldOne order by FldTwo desc) as seqnum
      from tblMain m
     ) m
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,  thanks for the answers and ways of showing different output.  I can add in an auto incrementing ID column and then I'll try the syntax that you've suggested.  Now that yourself and Hamlet have kindly given me the answers, I can now spend time working out *how* they work (very useful for the next time).  I've been reading up on partitioning at a table level as a way of splitting my data into smaller chunks (but have to wait for my Ent. License!).  I didn't know that you could use it dynamically like that.  Thanks again.

Comment: @EyePeaSea - partitioning at a table level is different than partitioning in a statement like this.  At a table level, it's really more a way to deal with file sizes (and related access times).  When used in a statement like this, it's conceptually closer to `GROUP BY` ('every time you see a new value in fldOne, start over...').  `PARTITION BY` would be (I'm assuming) something specified in the standard as to how it returns data.  A table partition is an implementation/optimization detail.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - Thanks for that.  It's something I need to read up on :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
SELECT SUM(fldThree) as ExpectedSum
FROM
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fldOne ORDER BY fldTwo DSEC) Rn
        FROM tblMain) as A
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Comment: Hamlet - that's great, thank you.  It does exactly what I'm trying to do and using the example table I gave, it works perfectly.  I now need to try it on the real table, which is obviously a bit more complex (so out comes the desk calculator to use on the real data).